# Angular to convert Date and Time Data with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have some unique data that I need to convert

Need to convert `"01/23/2017"` to `23-Jan-17 (Fri)`

Also need to convert `0238`    // I'm thinking that this is 2 hours and 38 minutes?

Finally convert `15:00`   // I assume military?  to `3:00pm`   ?
Sample data

```
"ArrivalDate": "01/23/2017",
"DepartureDate": "01/23/2017",
"DepartureAirport": "ORD",
"DepartureTime": "15:00",
"ArrivalAirport": "MCO",
"ArrivalTime": "18:38",
"TravelTime": "0238",
```

Comment: Sorry to say but the question is very confusing?? What is expected and what is actual values?

Comment: Do you have more code there? maybe you can provide a fiddle?

Comment: So where is your code attempt and what is the question?

Comment: added in sample data

Comment: you can use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to deal with date formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two AngularJS filters using these methods `getTravelDateFormatted` and `getTravelDateFormatted`:

```js
var getTravelDateFormatted = function (str) {
      var daysNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        d = new Date(str),
        day = d.getDate(),
        month = monthNames[d.getMonth()],
        year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2),
        dayName = daysNames[d.getDay()];
      return day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' (' + dayName + ')';
    },
    getTravelTimeFormatted = function (str) {
      var hours = Math.trunc(str / 60),
        minutes = str % 60;          
      return hours + ':' + minutes;
    };

console.log(getTravelDateFormatted('01/23/2017'));
console.log(getTravelTimeFormatted('0238'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have provide very less information, i could only give you some suggestion below:

It's better you can make your input is in datetime format, like 1482826055407, then you can get any displayed date format you like via angular date filter or you can create a custom date filter.

Here is an example of custom date filter which used moment to support globalization, If you don't need that feature, you can replace it with angular [$filter('date')](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) service.

```
    angular.module('aaa.ccc')
        .filter('momentDate', [
        function () {
            'use strict';
            return function (timestamp) {
                if(!isNaN(parseInt(timestamp))){
                    return moment(parseInt(timestamp)).format('L');
                }

            };
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angularjs date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

First of all you need to convert string to date `$scope.someDate = new Date('01/23/2017')`

Then use angular filter in the view `{{someDate | date:'dd-MMM-yy (EEE)'}}`

Or you can use date filter via [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in controller.